# How can I do insert into Blob in SQLite using Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-xe3

I try to insert into blob field in SQLite with Delphi XE3.

I've been using TDBXCommand and TSQLConnection like this. 
but blob field is not inserted and even i cannnot get any result from query

```
procedure TDBXCommandHelper.Init(const AQry: String);
begin
  Parameters.ClearParameters;
  Close;
  Prepare;
  Text := AQry;
end;

procedure dmDB.InsertPicture;
const
  QRY = 'INSERT INTO Memo(Picture) VALUES(?)';
var
  LTransaction: TDBXTransaction;
  LBlob: TDBXParameter;
  LStream: TFileStream;
begin
  LTransaction := FDBCon.BeginTransaction;
  LStream := TFileStream.Create('d:\sample.bmp', fmOpenRead);
  LBlob := TDBXParameter.Create;
  try
    try
      FDBXCmd := FDBCon.DBXConnection.CreateCommand;
      FDBXCmd.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DbxSQL;
      FDBXCmd.Init(QRY);

      LBlob.DataType := TDBXDataTypes.BlobType;
      LBlob.SubType := TDBXSubDataTypes.BinarySubType;
      LBlob.Value.SetStream(LStream, False);
      FDBXCmd.Parameters.AddParameter(LBlob);
      FDBXCmd.ExecuteUpdate;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        FDBCon.RollbackFreeAndNil(LTransaction);
    end;
    FDBCon.CommitFreeAndNil(LTransaction);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LStream);
    FreeAndNil(LBlob);
  end;
end;
```

using TSQLConnection but i cannot get any result

```
procedure TInsertThread.NoteInsertExcute;
const
  QRY = 'INSERT INTO Memo(Picture) VALUES(:Picture)';
var
  LTransaction: TDBXTransaction;
  LParams: TParams;
  LStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  LTransaction := FDBCon.BeginTransaction;
  LParams := TParams.Create(nil);
  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  LStream.LoadFromFile(FValues.Values[NAME_PICTURE]);
  try
    LParams.CreateParam(ftBlob, 'Picture', ptInput);
    LParams.ParamByName('Picture').LoadFromStream(LStream, ftBlob);
    FDBCon.Execute(QRY, LParams);
    FDBCon.CommitFreeAndNil(LTransaction);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LStream);
    FreeAndNil(LParams);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You can encode the content of LStream(memory stream) into a base64 string and push that into your db field.

Comment: What does this "INSERT INTO Memo(Picture)" mean? SQLite3 has no column definition, i.e. only some "affinity". You can insert any kind of data in any column. Try to remove the "Memo()". SQLite3 handles blob with no problem.

Comment: thank you for anwser.
Memo is Table Name and table is define like this..
`CREATE TABLE [Memo] (
[ID] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[UserID] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Date] TEXT  NULL,
[Type] TEXT  NOT NULL,
[Value] TEXT  NOT NULL,
[Picture] BLOB  NULL
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
function GetFileAsBytesValue(AFileName: TFileName): TArray<Byte>;
var
  Len: Integer;
  LStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    LStream.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    Len := LStream.Size;

    SetLength(Result, Len);
    Move(LStream.Memory^, Result[0], Len);
  finally
    LStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure dmDB.InsertPicture;
const
  QRY = 'INSERT INTO Memo(Picture) VALUES(?)';
var
  LTransaction: TDBXTransaction;
  LDBXCmd: TSQLQuery;
  LParam: TParam;
begin
  LTransaction := FDBCon.BeginTransaction;
  LDBXCmd := TSQLQuery.Create(FDBCon);
  try
    try
      LDBXCmd.SQLConnection := FDBCon;
      LDBXCmd.SQL.Text := QRY;
      LParam := LDBXCmd.Params.CreateParam(ftBlob, 'Picture', ptInput);
      LParam.AsBlob := GetFileAsBytesValue('d:\sample.bmp');
      LDBXCmd.ExecSQL;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        FDBCon.RollbackFreeAndNil(LTransaction);
    end;
    FDBCon.CommitFreeAndNil(LTransaction);
  finally
    LDBXCmd.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

That's easy like:

```
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;  
  sq: TSQLQuery;  
begin  
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  ms.LoadFromFile('C:\Pictures\l.jpg');
  if ms <> nil then
   begin
     sq := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
     sq.SQLConnection := con1;
     sq.SQL.Text := 'update db1 set picture= :photo ;';
     sq.Params.ParseSQL(sq.SQL.Text, true);
     sq.Params.ParamByName('photo').LoadFromStream(ms, ftBlob);
     sq.ExecSQL();
   end;
```

.
Where con1 is a TSQLConnection.